# How to check if URL is popuped in python

Tags: python

I have a script which at the end of its execution pops up the url.

Following is the code:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
website = os.path.join(path, "home.html")
webbrowser.open(website)
```

For each execution, it pops up the website. Is there a way, I can check if the website is already popped up. If it, then do not popup again?

Comment: Add the URLs you've already popped up to a `set` and check to see if it's in there before popping it up again.

Comment: @kindall : There is only one url. I am new to python, not sure how to do it. can u help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to poll webbrowser to see what is already open, but from your code you could keep a list of the URLs you've already opened and if not in that list open them. Depending on how large the list grows you would eventually need to use a database or something similar to handle it outside of memory.

Please note this is not complete, you would clear the list every time this script ran. You would need to use this concept as part of a larger functional  application, or write the list to desk at exit and read it back at start to maintain history.

example:

```
siteList = []
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
website = os.path.join(path,"home.html")
if website not in siteList:
    siteList.append(website)
    webbrowser.open(website)
```